# How to pass arguments to a command line program via bash?

Tags: bash, macos

I have a simple python script that takes a value from input and displays it like so:

```
x = raw_input ("say something:")

print x
```

I would like to run this *exact* program through a bash script and pass some parameter to the script so that it can be printed out on the screen? How would I go about doing this with the bash programming language?

p.s. I know about sys.argv, but I am looking for a bash based solution because I want to also be able to use this solution to pass values to command line programs where I may not necessarily be able to access the source code.

Comment: I may be old fashioned, but if you're looking for bash help, wouldn't it make sense to include your attempt to solve this .. in bash?

Answer (score 1):

Use positional parameters for this

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Your first arguement : $1" # Simlarly $2, $3 & so
echo "Whole arguements to the script : $@"
echo "Argument Count : ${#@}"
```

And run it like :

```
./script "xxmbabanexx" # here you have only one argument
```

For a quick reference , check [[ this ]](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams). For a complete reference, check the bash manpage, ie do

```
man bash
```

in the terminal and scroll down to `Positional Parameters` and then check `Special Parameters` section just below that.